# How can i give a common button of submission of the form which is generating many buttons

Tags: php

In this code when Google doc file is used to generate form we want  seperate submit button for all but with this we form separete submit buttons  .............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

```
     $url='https://docs.google.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $cat ='';
            if (($handle = fopen($url, "r")) !== FALSE)
            {
                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
                {
                    $totalrows = count($data);
                    for ($row=0; $row<=$totalrows; $row++)
                    {

                        if (($row % 6 == 0) && (strlen($data[$row])>0))
                        {
                        $answer = $row + 1;

                        $response["status"] = 1;

                        $response["price"] = $data[$answer+4];

                        $prodname = explode(' ',$response["prodname"]);
                        $prodname = $prodname[0];
                        if($_COOKIE[$prodname]) { $quantity = $_COOKIE[$prodname]; } else {        $quantity = "0"; }


                        if($response["subcat"] != 'Sub Category')
                        {
                            if($cat != $response["subcat"]){ 




                                echo '</div>';
                                echo '<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-r"  data-expanded-icon="arrow-d" data-content-theme="c">';
                                echo '<h3>'.$response["subcat"].'</h3>';
                                echo '<div class="ui-grid-a"><div class="ui-block- a">'.$response["prodname"].' ('.$response["prodnamemarathi"].') -  '.$response["quantity"].'<br/>Available in '.$month.'<br/>MRP: Rs.'.$response["price"].'</div>
                                <div class="ui-block-b">
                                <form action="?user='.$user.'" method="post"><input type="number"  name="quantity" data-mini="true" value="'.$quantity.'" /> 



                                <input type="hidden" name="subcat"  value="'.$response["subcat"].'">

                                <input type="hidden" name="price" value="'.$response["price"].'"> 
                                <input type="submit" value="Submit"></form></div></div>';


                                $cat = $response["subcat"];
                            }
                            else {
                                echo '<br/><div class="ui-grid-a"><div class="ui-block- a">'.$response["prodname"].' ('.$response["prodnamemarathi"].') -  '.$response["quantity"].'<br/>Available in '.$month.'<br/>MRP: Rs.'.$response["price"].'</div>
                                <div class="ui-block-b">
                                <form action="?user='.$user.'" method="post"><input type="number"  name="quantity" data-mini="true" value="'.$quantity.'"/><input type="hidden" name="subcat"  value="'.$response["subcat"].'">
                                <input type="hidden" name="prodname"  value="'.$response["prodname"].'"> 
                                <input type="hidden" name="prodnamemarathi"  value="'.$response["prodnamemarathi"].'"> 
                                <input type="hidden" name="price" value="'.$response["price"].'">
                                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                                </form></div></div>';

                            }
                        }

                        }
                    }   
                }


                fclose($handle);
            }
            echo '</div>';
```

?>

give some details

Comment: You need to add more detail.  Do all buttons need to link to the same URL?  Do they all have the same values?  Do they all need to submit the same data fields?  Do you have the option of using Javascript?

Comment: Your question is not really about PHP.  It's about HTML.  PHP just happens to be the code you are using to generate the HTML, but you could just as easily be using Ruby or Perl or just writing static HTML directly and the question would be just as applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Generate the form once, and just put the text input in the loop. Give them an array-style name.

```
<form action="page2" method="post">
    <?php
    while ($i <= 5):
        ?> <input type="text" name="size[]">
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Review Order">
</form>
```

In `page2`, you can access `$_POST['size']` as an array, which will contain all the inputs.

Comment: bro i have a code in php and i am getting a lot of problen can u help me